# Why are some fonts not getting applied when adding dynamic content to a ContentPresenter?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have basic `ContentPresenter` that I'm adding dynamic content to:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                  FontSize="16"
                  FontFamily="Consolas" />
```

If I'm adding content directly in the XAML file, like

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                  FontSize="16"
                  FontFamily="Consolas">
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
</ContentPresenter>
```

The `TextBlock` renders fine, with the font family `Consolas`.

If I add content dynamically in the code-behind, though

```
this.Presenter.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Some Text" };
```

the font family is the default font of the system and not `Consolas`

**BUT**

If I use a `ContentPresenter` with the font set to e.g `Courier New`

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                  FontSize="16"
                  FontFamily="Courier New" />
```

static *and* dynamically added content is rendered perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consolas font is not available see the list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202920(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: As I said in the question, the Consolas font works fine on a static content presenter

Comment: Pardon me, it seems like you're completely right. For the static text, I only checked in the VS Designer, where it's displayed properly and I just assumed it works, in the actual app, it doesn't work, thanks!

Comment: VS Designer reads the fonts from the computer and Consolas font is available on it. But when you deploy it on the device it will fallback to the default font.